Get signer public address before `Safe.init()`
in the answer here you are recommending to initialise the sdk with the public address of the signer.
What is the recommended way to fetch this?
The wagmi useAccount() hook it returns the address of the safe wallet.
We currently found a way to do so within the ethereum-window object in the connectors but this seems to be quite unreliable if user uses anything bar Metamask.

Is there a more realiable way to get the signer public address that works for all popular wallet providers?
currently I do it as such but again not so reliable when dealing with multiple wallet providers:
const EOAWallets = await wagmiProviderConfig.connectors[1].getAccounts();

const signerAddress = EOAWallets[0];

return await Safe.init({
  provider: window.ethereum,
  safeAddress: safeAddress,
  signer: signerAddress
});

Thanks

There are many ways to get the public address of a signer, but useAccount should work for users even if they are not using metamask.
For example: const account = useAccount(); console.log(account?.address)
You can then look at Wagmi's documentation on how to connect the useAccount hook to different wallets.
Note that you need the address of an owner of your safe (not the address of the Safe itself) for it to work.
Please let me know if it answered your question! Best, Louis

Hey Louis thanks for the quick response!
Unfortunately all that  useAccount  hook from wagmi returns is the information about the safe wallet when in a safe app. Which is fine and it works for executing and signing transactions as expected.
The issue is when I need to initialise the safe sdk with the safe.init call.
Since I do not have access to users EOA wallets private key I need their public key as the signer arg.
I updated the question above with the code snippet I use to get the address for the time being which is not very reliable

You can use ethers or viem to get the signer from window.ethereum, and then pass this entire signer object (not only the address) to the safe.init({ provider, safeAddress, signer }) call. You can find an example of that in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67836760/15551480
